# Unable to navigate to next page when clicked on button (JSF)

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I am currently learning jsf. I have written A simple jsf application where my target is to navigate from one page to another page. However, I am unable to navigate at all.

In my code there are two jsp files; one is `createcustomer.jsp` and the other is `viewCustomerDetails`. After the user enters data in `createcustomer.jsp` and clicks on the button it should move to next page (where it will display entered data in previous page in this page).

Below is my code. Can anyone find where I'm going wrong?<

**createCustomer.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h1 style="background-color:blue;color:white;">Create a new Customer</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<f:view>
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><h:inputText value="#{customer.name}"></h:inputText></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address:</td><td><h:inputText value="#{customer.address}"></h:inputText></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number:</td><td><h:inputText value="#{customer.phNumber}"></h:inputText></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email Address:</td><td><h:inputText value="#{customer.email_id}"></h:inputText></td></tr>

</table>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><h:commandButton value="Create Customer" action="viewCustomerDetails" /></td></tr>
</table>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**face-config.xml**

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

   <managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>customer</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>com.app.view.Customer</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

   <navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/createcustomer.jsp</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
    <!--  <from-action>#{customer.validate}</from-action>  --> 
   <from-outcome>viewCustomerDetails</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/viewCustomerDetails.jsp</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>

</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Customer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What issues you are facing? Also worth mentioning how you defined your web.xml.

Comment: iam not getting any issue, page is not getting submitted when clicked on button create customer

Comment: @developer: your problem is answered by point 1 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 Further, I want to remark that JSP is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0 more than 3 years ago. Also, navigation rules in faces-config are obsolete since JSF 2.0 implicit navigation feature. Perhaps you're reading poor or out of date JSF books/tutorials/resources. Please make sure that you learn JSF based on right and up to date resources, or it would only end up in headache and disaster. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Since you've mentioned you're learning to work with JSF, do you know about using Facelets? Think this is worth taking a look at, note this is JUST for the sake of helping you (not directly related to the question). Facelets fully supports JSF 2.0, which JSP does not. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197189/1336310

Comment: +1 @Aquillo. I *strongly* recommend using Facelets, JSF 2.2, CDI, and all the latest Java EE _accoutrements_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, based on your code snipplet you have no `<h:form>` tag defined. Components such as `<h:commandButton>` need to be defined inside of one to function properly. Encase the content of your `<f:view>` inside an `<h:form>` and try again.

Comment: when is adde <h:form> tag, iam getting warning as unknown tag <h:form>

Comment: @developer: Dump that JSF 1.x book/tutorial/resource and look for a JSF 2.x one.

Comment: i have moved to new workspace which supports JSF 2.X but still iam getting same warning as above. Please suggest me to resolve